# Function call missing argument list warning

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading over "The C++ Programming Language - Fourth Edition" and I was typing up a simple exercise just to get a hang of C++ syntax and I accidentally stumbled across something that made me raise an eyebrow.  In short, I forgot to add `()` on `accept` in main:

```
bool accept()
{
    cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";

    char answer = 0;
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 'y')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

int main()
{
    accept;
}
```

This runs and compiles and produces (in VS2015) a

> C4551 - function call missing argument list

I've found myself reading [lambdas](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) and a bunch of questions on SO that should be be closed because they are mostly asking to "debug my code."

I figured that if the code compiles and runs, and the function contains a blocking statement (waiting for user input) and a return type, that all the code would get executed as expected regardless of missing the parentheses; that is not the case though.

Additionally, I figured I would change the call to `accept` in main, to `bool a = accept; cout << a;` to try and prevent any optimization (if that was what was actually happening), and that did not call the `accept()` code either.

What I'm curious to know is:

1. What is the call to `accept` getting compiled into?
2. Why isn't the code in `accept` getting called
3. Why is this only a warning, and not an error (I know I can change configuration to display it as error, I'm more so questioning how this is accepted syntax by default when actual result differs from expected result so "dramatically?"  This question might be opinion-based, omit it if you agree it is.)
4. Running the `bool a = accept; cout << a;` code in main produces `1` as the output.  How can this be when `false` is the default bool value (in C# at least) and there is nothing to return a true value since the accept code does not get executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the C++ compiler complain when I use functions without parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082329/why-doesnt-the-c-compiler-complain-when-i-use-functions-without-parentheses) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073066/g-calling-function-without-parenthesis-not-f-but-f-why-always-return

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb: While it is close, he does ask a couple of other things that have to do with function pointers and decaying to `bool`. So it's not a complete duplicate.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb the answer in the "duplicate" only answers a portion of my question.  The "duplicate" question's title is just about the exact opposite of what I was experiencing, as my compiler was giving the warning, hence me using the warning text as the question title so it's easily found in searches when others come across the same warning.  The other questions using my same title ask "why doesn't my code work," so it might be more worthwhile to go close those vs. closing my Q when the "dupe" you found is (well not a dupe, and) barely searchable.

Comment: I saw all 4 questions answered in the two referenced questions.  You just have to read the answers.  Maybe I am missing something, but I remember reading answers for all points raised in your question.  Question format is not the issue.  Its the question content.  I still believe its a dupe.  Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. There is no "call to `accept`". See #3.
2. Because of #1.
3. The use of a function name *without* function call syntax (ie: `()`) means that you're accessing the function itself. You could, for example, store it in a function pointer (through function-to-pointer decaying):

   ```
   using my_func = bool(*)(); //Function that takes nothing and returns a bool.
   my_func var = accept; //Store a pointer to `accept`.
   ```

   You could then issue `var();`, which would call `accept`.

   However, because you never store the function, the compiler guesses that you probably meant to *call* the function, not to access the function's pointer. `accept;` however is a legal C++ statement, therefore the compiler cannot error on it. It can emit a warning, since the statement accomplishes nothing and you probably meant to call the function. It's no different from a statement like `1;`: perfectly legal, but utterly useless.
4. It does this because of C++ trickery. Non-null pointers decay to the boolean value `true`. And `accept` decays to a function pointer that is not null. Therefore, when converted to a `bool`, it will be `true`. You're still not *calling* the function.

Answer (score 8):

In C++, any expression followed by a semicolon is a legal statement. (Why? Because C let you do this, I think). That means that all of the following are legal statements:

```
 5;
 3 + 5;
 1 % 2 == 0;
```

The effect of a statement of this form is that the expression is evaluated and then discarded. A good optimizing compiler would just eliminate all of the logic here, since none of these have any side-effects.

In your case, writing

```
accept;
```

is a legal statement because `accept` is an expression evaluating to a reference to the function `accept`. That means that `accept;` as a statement means "evaluate the address of `accept`, then discard it." The reason that no function is called here is that a function name by itself doesn't invoke the function; you need the parentheses (the function call operator) to actually make the call. This is useful, for example, if you want to pass a function into another function. For example, you might want to pass a comparison function into `std::sort`, like this:

```
std::sort(range.begin(), range.end(), nameOfMyComparisonFunction)
```

Here, it would be a real problem if this tried calling `nameOfMyComparisonFunction`, since the arguments can't be known until the sorting routine starts off.

So why is this a warning and not an error? Well, it's perfectly legal C++ code, so the compiler can't compliantly call it an error. However, the compiler is right to flag it as a warning, since it almost certainly means you made an error. That said, most compilers have some setting that reports warnings as errors, and if you crank up the warning level high enough the compiler probably *would* say "this is so suspicious that I'm going to assume you messed something up."

As to your last one - why does

```
bool a = accept;
```

end up setting `a` to `true?` In C++, any non-null pointer implicitly converts to true and any null pointer implicitly converts to false. In C++, functions are implicitly convertible to pointers to themselves, so in this case `accept` evaluates to the address of the `accept` function, which is non-null, so it sets `a` to `true`. When you then write

```
cout << a << endl;
```

the value is printed as 1, because `bool` values are printed as 1 and 0 rather than `true` and `false` by default. That said, you could write

```
cout << boolalpha << a << endl;
```

and you'll see `true` printed instead.

Hope this helps!